# Coreplot axis gridlines only under the plotline

Tags: ios, iphone, graph, core-plot

I want to show gridlines only under the plotline something like this:

[image]

seems like i have to do something with areafill. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid lines all have to be the same length. Instead, use a bar plot to draw the vertical lines under the line plot. Use the same plot data for both plots.